# How to send logoff in Remote Desktop ActiveX control?

Tags: winapi, activex, remote-desktop

I'm writing a Delphi application which has an intergrated [Remote Desktop ActiveX Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383022%28VS.85%29.aspx) (a.k.a MSTSCLib - but specifically TMsRdpClient9).  I am able to successfully connect to and log in to the target machine, and I am able to Disconnect from the target machines using RDPClient.RequestClose() or RDPClient.Disconnect(), but I need to know how to send a Logoff/Logout command to the RDP Client.

I have gone through every interface of the control, and I cannot find any command which seems to do this functionality.  I have also gone through the documentation linked above, and the method I need to use seems to elude me.

I have also searched Google, and Stack Overflow for similar questions, and have found none.

Can somebody please give me a hand

Comment: I question the tagging. It's not language specific so include no languages. Tag with winapi.